# If a deaf person is not counted towards a minyan because they cannot hear, does the same rule apply for one who doesn't speak/understand Hebrew?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, hearing

My understanding is Halacha states a deaf or mute person doesn't count towards a minyan as they do not have the ability to fully participate. The deaf person cannot hear what is being said and the mute person cannot vocalize as part of the minyan.

**My question is this:**

If the above statement is true because the deaf person cannot understand what is being said, is it not reasonable to assume the same rule would apply to a Jew with no Hebrew background? Meaning they are standing in a room and from their perspective, everyone is speaking gibberish. Isn't that situation somewhat equivalent to the Jew who is deaf? Both are somewhat separated from the group in this regard, are they not?

Comment: "If the above statement is true" Instead of assuming it, why not ask to confirm it first?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/27891 the end of item 6 and item seven address your premise and even hint to an answer to your actual question. Note 44 on this page https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zimmun might also be relevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why remove my reply to you? I was addressing why I framed the question the way I did.

Comment: @Michael I didn't delete any comments on this post. That said if, I encourage you to respond to my comment and all comments where possible by editing your post to clarify it in light of the comment. Edit to improve your post and make the comment obsolete. That's the best way.